# Add labels to geom_histogram independent of the number associated with x or y aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the number of top 100 prospects every MLB team has from Baseball America. I have a column for the organization, players, and their rank on the list. For instance, this is for the Boston Red Sox.

```
BA_100 <- data.frame(Organization = c("BOS", "BOS", "BOS", "BOS"), Player = c("Marcelo Mayer", "Roman Anthony", "Kyle Teel", "Ceddanne Rafaela"), Rank = c(14, 21, 62, 94), Total = c(4, 4, 4, 4), Count = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I aim to order teams (x-axis) based on the number of prospects listed in descending order. This is the code I'd use to create a plot, in this case, only displaying what it'd look like for the Red Sox.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbplotr)
library(ggtext)

BA_100 %>%
  filter(Organization == "BOS") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(Organization, desc(Total)), y = Count, color = Organization, fill = Organization)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_mlb(type = "primary") +
  scale_color_mlb(type = "secondary") +
  labs(title = "Number of Ranked Prospects (**Baseball America**)", x = NULL, y = "Count", fill = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_mlb_scoreboard_logo(size = 0.8),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom", legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image: BA_100 Plot]
This code with the aforementioned packages loaded returns the plot attached. How can I put the rank of each player in those four boxes? In this case, it'd be the numbers 14, 21, 62, and 94, since that's how their prospects are positioned on this list.

I tried using statbin() to add the labels, but I ran into many errors. I had issues with having an x and y aesthetic, an x aesthetic that isn't numeric, etc. Geom_label() and geom_text() haven't given me any success either.

Comment: Unfortunately your example data is lacking variables `Total` and `Count`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for noticing that! I just adjusted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `geom_histogram` you could simply use a `geom_col`. To add your labels you could use a `geom_text` with `position = position_stack(vjust = .5)`:

```r
library(mlbplotR)
library(ggtext)
library(tidyverse)

BA_100 |>
  filter(Organization == "BOS") |>
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = fct_reorder(Organization, desc(Total)),
      y = Count, color = Organization, fill = Organization
    )
  ) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste(Player, Rank, sep = ": ")),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_mlb(type = "primary") +
  scale_color_mlb(type = "secondary") +
  labs(title = "Number of Ranked Prospects (**Baseball America**)", x = NULL, y = "Count", fill = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text.x = element_mlb_scoreboard_logo(size = 0.8),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]